# Calculating distances between points in a CFD mesh

Tags: python, numpy

I have a structured Mesh that has around 3e+6 points and

Please view the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUkQ.jpg

Each point in the physical domain (Euclidean) has an index (*i, j and k*) in the computational domain.

I need to iterate over the computational domain indices and make calculations with corresponding points.

For example, length in direction *i* at a given Index, would be (pseudocode):
 length = vec_len(point(*i+1, j, k*) - point(*i, j, k*))

Also it's important to find out the ratio of lengths at a given point. For example, I would calculate two nearby lengths in direction *i* and divide between them.

What I came up with takes too much time and probably doesn't exploit the full potential NumPy has to offer.

I made a ndarray filled with zeros that would hold all of the mesh XYZ coordinates.

```
block_data =numpy.zeros((i_dim,  j_dim, k_dim, 3), dtype='float')
```

The number 3 corresponds for 3 elements, x, y and z.

So if I'd like the z values at *i=3, j=7, k=10* it would be:

```
Z = block_data[3][7][10][2]
```

A point in the Euclidean space would be a (1,3) ndarray:

```
point = block_data[i][j][k]
```

The way I calculate the length between two points is:

```
numpy.linalg.norm(point2 - point1)
```

Only the length calculation takes around 1.5ms and I would like to calculate distances in all point and all directions:
3e+6 * 3.

I think there is a problem with the approach of the way I construct the main block ndarray (block_data), because it limits me with making the calculation on only two points at a time, that is only two small (1,3) ndarrays.
If I remember correctly, it not so efficient  to make calculations on small arrays.

How could I approach the problem and make the run times faster? Is there a book recommend for these kind of problems? Thanks :-)

Comment: for a point in 3D cartesian space with a rectangular grid each point has 6 neighboring points. So you want to calculate the distance to each of the neighboring points, that means 6 distances per point (excluding points at the border)?

Comment: @Scotty1- No. I would like to choose a specific direction in the computational domain (for the 2D example in the photo, I can choose between i or j) and calculate the distance to the point in the next index in the front (let's say I choose i, and I want to know the length at I=5, so I'll get the point in i=6 and compute the norm between them) Thing is I need to calculate ratios, it's more important, but for a ratio I need to calculate two lengths.

Comment: Ok, if you need to calculate only two lengths and not many more, you can stick with your approach. If you want to calculate alot of lengths in one step, it will be worth using a vectorized approach, but not for two lengths.

Comment: @Scotty1- if for example I need to find out what would be the maximum ratio in direction i, there is need to iterate all over the mesh (of course, there is need to check every j index. So for a 2D mesh thats i*j times) and find the maximum. It works fine if you want only one length, but if, like I said, you would like to find out what would be the maximum ratio, the "length" method would be executed 3e+6 times minus the borders. Runing np.linalg.norm() on my ndarray takes 1.5e-3. It would take too much time.

Comment: I added a solution which should be alot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the euclidean distance in an array of this size, I recommend using a vectorized approach:

```
def euclid_dist(array, direction):
    if direction == 'i':  # make shifted views depending on the direction
        p1 = array[:-1, :, :]
        p2 = array[1:, :, :]
    elif direction == 'j':
        p1 = array[:, :-1, :]
        p2 = array[:, 1:, :]
    elif direction == 'k':
        p1 = array[:, :, :-1]
        p2 = array[:, :, 1:]
    else:
        raise ValueError('direction ' + direction + ' not known.')

    # get euclidean distance for all points in direction:
    euc_dist = (((p1 - p2)*(p1 - p2)).sum(axis=3))**0.5

    return euc_dist
```

Using a small test-array with:

```
arr = np.random.randint(-20, 20, 5*5*5*3).reshape(5, 5, 5, 3)
eu_i = euclid_dist(arr, 'i')
eu_j = euclid_dist(arr, 'j')
# test some values:
print(eu_i[2, 1, 2] == np.linalg.norm(arr[2, 1, 2] - arr[3, 1, 2]))
# Out 64: True
print(eu_j[1, 1, 1] == np.linalg.norm(arr[1, 1, 1] - arr[1, 2, 1]))
# Out 65: True
```

Some timings for a big array with `8e6` points and `24e6` values:

```
big_arr = np.random.rand(200, 200, 200, 3)
%timeit euclid_dist(big_arr, 'i')
# 644 ms ± 57.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Imho that is quite fast for an array of such size. :) If I read your timings correctly, this is about 19000 times faster than your code.

Comment: Just added this to my code with an option to find max ratio and it's working great! Have to say I've learned a lot. Thanks :-)